# NodeMCU ESP8266 httpclient library dropping connection after 240 successful connections

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a NodeMCU ESP-12E dev board I am attempting to talk to a PHP web page on an externally hosted server, every 5 seconds.  The PHP page returns a JSON encoded string that I plan to later parse on the NodeMCU.  I have been able to connect and receive the expected reply, but after the program runs for about 20 minutes it stops connecting and I receive a "connection refused" after 240 successful connections.  It will continue to reply that the connection was refused if I let the program continue.  If I press the reset button, it immediately connects again and receives the expected JSON string, 240 times and then back to "connection refused.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

I am using the latest version of the Arduino IDE, 1.6.9 with the libraries found [HERE](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino).

Here is a sample of the return I correctly get, 240 times.

```
{"user":"Craig","address":{"s1":"1111 My Street","city":"MyTown","state":"PA","zip":"18000"},"command":{"outputs":{"5":"1","4":"1"}}}
```

Here is my Arduino IDE Sketch.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char *cssid = "myssid";
const char *cpass = "mypassword";

unsigned int counter = 1;


unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 5000;

void setup() {
  delay(500);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(cssid);

  WiFi.begin(cssid, cpass);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis; 

    HTTPClient http;
    String payload;
    http.begin("http://www.mywebsiteurl.com/data_return_page.php");
    int httpCode = http.GET();

    if(httpCode > 0) {
          if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
              payload = http.getString();
              Serial.print(counter);
              Serial.print(": ");
              Serial.println(payload);
              counter++;
          }
      } else {
          Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
          Serial.printf("error: %s\n", httpCode);
      }

    http.end();
    }

}
```

Comment: Connecting to http://httpbin.org/get instead of your own server yields the same result?

Comment: I will try that now, give me 20 min to reply

Comment: Same result, after 240.. [HTTP] GET... failed, error: connection refused
error:

Comment: And how many times does loop() gets executed? You could try setting HTTPClient http variable static, or making it global variable, or `setReuse(true);` which should enable socket reuse.

Comment: The loop continues running indefinitely, but continues to output "[HTTP] GET... failed, error: connection refused
error: " over and over.  I have tried the setReuse(true); which did not have any effect.  I suspect it's a memory issue.  I'll try your suggestions of making it static or global and report back.

Comment: New Edit: I adjusted the timing from 5 seconds to .5 seconds and I'm well over 800 successful requests.  Perhaps something is going to sleep after 20 minutes?

Comment: I tried making it global, static, and the setReuse(true) and I get the same results.  It's got to be something to do with time, it always fails around the 20 minute mark.  I've adjusted the delay to .5 second and it runs for over 2000 requests.  I set the delay to 10 minutes and it fails on the 3rd request.  I've even changed the sketch to [this example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpClient/BasicHttpClient.ino) and it does the same thing.

Comment: Did you ever consider that it's neither your sketch nor the remote server but what's in between? Your WiFi AP or other network components.

Comment: Well I had considered that, but didn't act on it..  I should have..  I switched to an cellular hot spot and it's been running for an hour without issue.  I use an Apple Airport, so I'll have to look into that.  Thank you!